# How to access specific value in this 'json'?

Tags: json, angular, ionic-framework

I'm accessing an URL like http://localhost/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=process

and it returns something like this :

```
{
    "status": "processing",
    "icon": "test"
    "testing": 0
}
```

I've tried everything to get the `status` but it never works. I precise that it is an Ionic app.

Here is my code (in console.log, everything that I've tried):

```
  process() {
    let url: any = 'http://localhost/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=process'
    this.httpIonic.get(url, null, null)
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data);
        console.log(response.data[0].status)
        console.log(response.data[0]['status'])
        console.log(response.data.data.status)
        console.log(response.data.status)
        console.log(response[0]['status']);
        console.log(response[0].status)
        console.log(response[0])
        console.log(response.status)
      })
  }
```

It always returns either nothing, either everything.

What am I doing wrong ? 
Thanks

Comment: `response.data['status']` for ionic

Comment: can you add output of console.log(response);

Answer (score 0):

standing their [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http/) ‘response.status’ should be the right one... I would add the catch so to get more info if something’s going wrong; 
furthermore I would even try to replace both null with empty objects

Comment: Thank you for your answer but response.status answers 200. That's not what I'm looking for, I'm looking for the 'status' field

Comment: @Ferdinand u’re right, ...sometimes u get something in response.data?.. when not check the catch outcomes, if nothing happen then there might be a problem. Have You tried to replace the nulls with {}?

Comment: Yes thank you @fedeghe, I've solved it. Actually it was because it was a string, so it needed to be converted to json using JSON.parse. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

After getting the response. put that value in in a variable. after that try to access it. it will work.

example

```
this.val = result;
      this.MediaList=this.val.problemActionList;
      value.MediaList=this.MediaList.MediaList;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using JSON.parse(response) and then refer to response.status.